# Members of derived inner classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

**Goal**

I am working on implementing an `IntegerRing`, which is a structure in abstract algebra. This type of ring is an Abelian group (something that I have already implemented) under addition. Rings are equipped with two operators, + and *.

**Choice of implementation**

For this reason, I have decided to define `IntegerGroup` as class that has `GroupElement`s that have the operators. The complete, working code for that is found below:

*IntegerGroup.h*

```
#ifndef DATAGROUP_H
#define DATAGROUP_H

#include "Array.h"

#include <iostream>

// This group is the integers mod n
// multiplication in integer group is simply integer addition modulo n
class IntegerGroup
{
    public:
        IntegerGroup();
        IntegerGroup(int);
        class GroupElement
        {
            int m;
            IntegerGroup* group;
            public: 
                GroupElement();
                GroupElement(int, IntegerGroup*);
                ~GroupElement();
                GroupElement operator*(const GroupElement&);
                GroupElement operator*=(const GroupElement&);
                bool operator==(const GroupElement&);
                bool operator!=(const GroupElement&);
                int val() const;
                friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const GroupElement& e)
                {
                    return (o << e.m);
                }

        };
        GroupElement identity() const;
        int size() const;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const IntegerGroup& g)
        {
            return (o << g.elements);
        }
    private:
        int n;
        //GroupElement * identity;
        Array<GroupElement> elements;
        void createNewElement(int);
};

#endif
```

*IntegerGroup.cpp*

```
#include "IntegerGroup.h"

#include <new>
#include <iostream>

IntegerGroup::IntegerGroup()
{

}

IntegerGroup::IntegerGroup(int n)
 : n(n), elements(Array<IntegerGroup::GroupElement>(n))
{
    //this is to have integers in [0,n-1]
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        this->createNewElement(j);
    }
}

void IntegerGroup::createNewElement(int m)
{
    // create new GroupElement
    GroupElement newElement(m, this);
    // store it at index m in elements
    this->elements[m] = newElement;
}

IntegerGroup::GroupElement::GroupElement() 
    : group(0)
{

}


IntegerGroup::GroupElement::GroupElement(int m, IntegerGroup * g)
    : group(g)
{
    // this->m must be in [0, g->size() - 1]
    this->m = m % g->size();
    if (this->m < 0) this->m = g->size() + this->m;
}

IntegerGroup::GroupElement::~GroupElement()
{
    if (this->group)
    {
        this->group = 0;
    }
}

IntegerGroup::GroupElement IntegerGroup::identity() const
{
    // IntegerGroup consists of all integers in [0, n-1], and identity is 0
    return this->elements[0];
}

// this group is simply the integers mod n, and should be populated integers in [0,n-1]
// thus, multiplication is simply a matter of returning the element at index (a+b)%n
IntegerGroup::GroupElement IntegerGroup::GroupElement::operator*(const IntegerGroup::GroupElement& b)
{
    // if the group is not defined
    if (!this->group)
        // we simply perform integer multiplication
        return GroupElement(this->val() * b.val());
    // otherwise, perform group multiplication
    return GroupElement((this->val() + b.val()) % this->group->size());
}

IntegerGroup::GroupElement IntegerGroup::GroupElement::operator*=(const IntegerGroup::GroupElement& b)
{
    return ((*this) = (*this) * b);
}

bool IntegerGroup::GroupElement::operator==(const IntegerGroup::GroupElement& b)
{
    return this->m == b.m;
}

bool IntegerGroup::GroupElement::operator!=(const IntegerGroup::GroupElement& b)
{
    return !(*this == b);
}

int IntegerGroup::GroupElement::val() const { return this->m; }

int IntegerGroup::size() const { return this->n; }
```

Array.cpp, Array.h are merely templated wrapper classes. The code to that is also already working. You can find the files for them [on](https://github.com/MikeWarren2014/IntegerRing/blob/master/Array.h) [GitHub](https://github.com/MikeWarren2014/IntegerRing/blob/master/Array.cpp) here, or you could use `std::vector` instead. (It just now occurred to me that right now, I could do that.)

**The problem**

When I tried creating `IntegerRing`, and compiling, I got a myriad of bizarre errors, most of which had to do with the class's own functions using private class data.

Here is my implementation thus far of `IntegerRing`:

*IntegerRing.h*

```
#ifndef INTEGERRING_H
#define INTEGERRING_H

#include "IntegerGroup.h"
#include "Operators.h"

class IntegerRing : public IntegerGroup
{
    public:
        class Element : public IntegerGroup::GroupElement
        {
            public: 
                using IntegerGroup::GroupElement;
                /*Element();
                Element(int);
                Element(int, IntegerRing*);
                ~Element();*/
                operator IntegerGroup::GroupElement() { return IntegerGroup::GroupElement(); }
                Element(const IntegerGroup::GroupElement& el)
                {
                    // copy everything from el into *this
                    this->m = el.m;
                    this->group = el.group;
                }
                /*Element operator+(const Element&);
                Element operator-(const Element&);
                Element operator*(const Element&);
                Element operator+=(const Element&);
                Element operator-=(const Element&);
                Element operator*=(const Element&);*/

        };
        Element identity(Operators);
    private:

};

#endif
```

*IntegerRing.cpp*

```
#include "IntegerRing.h"
#include "IntegerGroup.h"
#include "Operators.h"

/*IntegerRing::Element::Element()
{

}*/

/*IntegerRing::Element(const IntegerGroup::GroupElement& el)
{
    // copy everything from el into *this
    this->m = el.m;
    this->group = el.group;
}
/*
IntegerRing::Element IntegerRing::Element::operator+(const IntegerRing::Element& b)
{
    // IntegerRing is simply Abelian group under addition
    // thus, we treat the elements like group elements first, multiply under that group, and cast to ring elements
    return (IntegerRing::Element)(((IntegerGroup::GroupElement)(*this)) * ((IntegerGroup::GroupElement)b));
}

IntegerRing::Element IntegerRing::Element::operator-(const IntegerRing::Element& b)
{
    int val;
    // if this has a group
    if (this->group)
    {
        // compute (this->m - b.m) % this->group->size()
        val = (this->m - b.m) % this->group->size();
        // if that value is negative, add this->group->size() to it
        if (val < 0) val = this->group->size() + val;
    }
    // otherwise, val is simply the integer difference of this->m,b.m
    else val = this->m - b.m;
    // return element with this value
    return Element(val);
}

IntegerRing::Element IntegerRing::Element::operator*(const IntegerRing::Element& b)
{
    if (this->group)
        return IntegerRing::Element((this->m - b.m) % this->group->size());
    return IntegerRing::Element(this->m - b.m);
}

IntegerRing::Element IntegerRing::Element::operator+=(const IntegerRing::Element& b)
{
    return ((*this) = (*this) + b);
}

IntegerRing::Element IntegerRing::Element::operator-=(const IntegerRing::Element& b)
{
    return ((*this) = (*this) - b);
}

IntegerRing::Element IntegerRing::Element::operator*=(const IntegerRing::Element& b)
{
    return ((*this) = (*this) * b);
}
*/
IntegerRing::Element IntegerRing::identity(Operators op)
{
    // if op is ADDITIVE
    if (op == ADDITIVE)
        // return what the base version of this method would return
        return (IntegerRing::Element)(((IntegerGroup::GroupElement*)this)->identity());
    // multiplicative identity requested, and it is 1
    return (IntegerRing::Element)this->elements[0];
}
```

*Operators.h*

```
#ifndef OPERATORS_H
#define OPERATORS_H

enum Operators
{
    ADDITIVE, MULTIPLICATIVE
};

#endif
```

The compiler thinks the copy constructor for `IntegerRing::Element` is really a function that returns an `int`.

**Screenshot of errors**

Here is screenshot of errors: [image: All the errors I got at compilation time]

**How do I resolve all this?**

Comment: For the dependencies, my code is minimal.

Comment: Did you mean to say `IntegerRing::Element::Element` for the constructor and not just `IntegerRing::Element`?

Comment: That is what I meant. Good catch!

Comment: EDIT: Only one constructor wasn't needed, in `IntegerGroup::GroupElement`. I just removed it.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Post text itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my years of not using C++ for serious OOP like this has caused me to forget things. First of which: derived classes have access to `protected`,`public` members, and not `private` unless you declare derived class a `friend` in base class.

Second: how to write copy constructors. Sadly, derived classes have access to their own inherited `protected` data members, not base class's. To remedy this, I just write copy constructor like this:

```
IntegerRing::Element::Element(const IntegerGroup::GroupElement::GroupElement& el)
 : IntegerGroup::GroupElement(el)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you can't access class's private fields.
Inheritance/Nested Class do not change this.(Exception is inner class can always access it's enclosing class's any member(since C++11))

For the first error in log `using IntegerGroup::GroupElement;` should be `usingIntegerGroup::GroupElement::GroupElement;` inside `IntegerRing::Element`, by the way, I don't see the need of this class.

Comment: So, how should I get around this? Add getters and setters to base nested class? (NOTE: My school's server, which is the environment I am running this all in, doesn't have C++11)

Comment: Or maybe you can try to use the `friend` keyword?

Comment: And for your example, `IntegerGroup` does not need to contain the array at all.

Comment: I just had flashback: I could have just used `protected` in base class, instead of `private`

Comment: Years ago, I remember the last time I did some serious object-oriented programming in C++, came across this problem, and remedied it by using protected data members instead of private members.